# After using 2 loops in a list, the first element is removed from it automatically in Python

Tags: python, list, loops

I made a program in which the user enters some integers and python displays how many even and odd numbers you entered. The code is the following:

```
ev_od_list = []
even = []
odd = []

number = int(input("Enter an integer(entering 0 would end the process): "))

while number != 0:
    number = int(input("Enter an integer(entering 0 would end the process): "))
    ev_od_list.append(number)

for i in ev_od_list:
    if i % 2 == 0:
        even.append(i)

even.remove(0)
print("The number of even numbers you entered is:", len(even))

for j in ev_od_list:
    if j % 2 != 0:
        odd.append(j)       

print(ev_od_list)
print("The number of odd numbers you entered is:", len(odd))
```

And the output...

```
Enter an integer(entering 0 would end the process): 1
Enter an integer(entering 0 would end the process): 2
Enter an integer(entering 0 would end the process): 3
Enter an integer(entering 0 would end the process): 4
Enter an integer(entering 0 would end the process): 5
Enter an integer(entering 0 would end the process): 6
Enter an integer(entering 0 would end the process): 7
Enter an integer(entering 0 would end the process): 8
Enter an integer(entering 0 would end the process): 9
Enter an integer(entering 0 would end the process): 10
Enter an integer(entering 0 would end the process): 0
The number of even numbers you entered is: 5
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 0]
The number of odd numbers you entered is: 4
```

In the second last line, you may notice that 1 has been removed from the list automatically. So, why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is you have a first call to `input()` which is overwritten by another call of `input()` and append the number after the second `input()` call. Here is the working code with much optimisations:

```
even = []
odd = []

number = int(input("Enter an integer(entering 0 would end the process): "))

while number != 0:
    if number != 0:
        if number % 2 == 0:
            even.append(number)
        else:
            odd.append(number)
        number = int(input("Enter an integer(entering 0 would end the process): "))

print("The number of even numbers you entered is:", len(even))
print("The number of odd numbers you entered is:", len(odd))
```

Comment: Yes, sure. But I don't know how to mark yours as the answer.

Comment: Refer to this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235

Answer (score 2):

```
number = int(input("Enter an integer(entering 0 would end the process): "))

while number != 0:
    number = int(input("Enter an integer(entering 0 would end the process): "))
    ev_od_list.append(number)
```

You are not appending the 1st input. 1st input gets replace by 2nd input.
so in `while` loop, append first then ask next input.

```
number = int(input("Enter an integer(entering 0 would end the process): "))

while number != 0:
    ev_od_list.append(number)
    number = int(input("Enter an integer(entering 0 would end the process): "))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this solution :

```
ev_od_list = []
even = []
odd = []
number = None

while number != 0:
    number = int(input("Enter an integer(entering 0 would end the process): "))
    ev_od_list.append(number)

for i in ev_od_list:
    if i % 2 == 0:
        even.append(i)

even.remove(0)
print("The number of even numbers you entered is:", len(even))

for j in ev_od_list:
    if j % 2 != 0:
        odd.append(j)

print(ev_od_list)
print("The number of odd numbers you entered is:", len(odd))
```

Comment: I felt C/ C++ was better where you could first define what you are going to use and then do whatever you want. But in Python, I can use None. Okay, I didn't think so. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You get the first number and override the second one on it so it is lost. You can get the number inside the loop and define number with an arbitrary value outside the loop.

Also, i think you tried to remove the zero you can do it by `del ev_od_list[-1]` command which deletes the last element of the `ev_od_list` which is always zero.

```
ev_od_list = []
even = []
odd = []
number = 1
# number = int(input("Enter an integer(entering 0 would end the process): "))

while number != 0:
    number = int(input("Enter an integer(entering 0 would end the process): "))
    ev_od_list.append(number)

del ev_od_list[-1]

for i in ev_od_list:
    if i % 2 == 0:
        even.append(i)


print("The number of even numbers you entered is:", len(even))

for j in ev_od_list:
    if j % 2 != 0:
        odd.append(j)       

print(ev_od_list)
print(even)
print("The number of odd numbers you entered is:", len(odd))
```

Comment: This can also be done, but it's not necessary that the user enters 1, so that may not help then.